# Is this a Kruskal-Wallis Test?

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test

[image: Kruskal-Wallis Test]

This table shows the results of a Kruskal-Wallis test, but I am not sure what the column values represent. I thought the Kruskal-Wallis test statistic is always positive and that the test merely shows whether there is a difference between groups.  In the text, the author makes statements such as:

> Compared to all other burglary types, census blocks with low single event burglary, low repeat burglary, and low near-repeat burglary (n = 66) displayed significantly lower levels of concentrated disadvantage.

Are these results and conclusions possible with a Kruskal-Wallis test, or are there other analyses incorporated here?

Edit: I searched the full text for mentions of other analyses, but the author only references Kruskal-Wallis being used to create these results.

Comment: There's not enough context to be quite certain what the values in the table represent. It's possible that it's described elsewhere than the bit you have shown here.